# Посоветуйте хороший С++ компилятор под windows xp

Tags: c++

не могу найти С++ подходящий компилятор под windows xp с поддержкой стандарта С11. никто не подскажет где его можно взять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбирай себе из списка по уровню поддержки С++11 и С++14: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support